# Ajax Upload plugin does not bind click event

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, upload

I've downloaded the following plugin: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Unfortunately it does not work with the FileUploaderBasic (which is the one i have to use because i don't want the FileUploader capabilities)

I've tried to read the documentation countless times, and read the comments, but i can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
    element: document.getElementById('editProfileAvatarUploadButton'),
    action: 'ajax.php'
});
```

I don't get any errors in the console.

Can someone give me a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with FileUploaderBasic.  However, if you are trying to upload images via ajax, that will not work.  That my be why it's not working. Why don't you use jQuery AJAX to upload?

Comment: It doesn't bind the click event to the button/element i created. When i use the FileUploader "Class" it does bind it to it's own genereted button.

Comment: Choosing a better description than "does not work" will make your title stand out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass it a `button` option for the FileUploaderBasic class to work.

Like so:

```js
var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
    button: document.getElementById('editProfileAvatarUploadButton'),
    action: 'ajax.php'
});
```